# Establish AWS connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, aws-glue, cdata

Is there a way by which we can establish a connection from AWS to sql server and pull the data. I am aware of the method of using cdata connector with glue jobs and it looks promising but I want to explore options here. The idea is to pull the data from sql server to s3 bucket.

Comment: check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `from_options` method of GLUE to pull data from below data stores

`s3, mysql, postgresql, redshift, sqlserver, oracle, and dynamodb`

and dump wherever you required.

More Information on

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-reader.html

Comment: Thanks for the document, this would require a driver jar file to connect. Which jar file it is going to be? I was checking cdata documentation https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/sql-jdbc-aws-glue.rst, Need to know if we can use any other drivers here.